# wicd does not automatically REconnect

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, wicd

I connect wirelessly to a router using wicd 1.7.2.4 on slackware 14.  If I am not actively using the internet connection for some time then I lose the connection, but wicd does not automatically reconnect, even though this option is checked for the WPA2 network concerned. The wicd-client gui at that point shows "Not Connected" in its status line. If I then press the Connect button for that network it instantly reconnects.

There is no entry in /var/log/wicd/wicd.log to show that connection has been lost, nor that it is trying to reconnect, as far as the log is concerned everything is still A-OK.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to find any convenient method of fixing this through wicd itself, because it required killing both monitor.py and wicd-daemon.py and restarting them, which must be done as root.

But a much simpler approach does the job, that is keep the connection alive, as with this user level script

```
  while [ 0 ]; do
    a=$(ping -c 1 google.com)
    if [ "$a" == "ping: unknown host google.com" ]; then
      echo "Connection lost $(date)" > $HOME/connect.lost
      break
    fi
    sleep 6
  done
```

Comment: How does this work? Is "connect.lost" a special file monitored for by wicd?

Comment: No, it just kept pinging google while maybe I was making no other use of the web at all, i.e. just busywork for wicd to keep it active. I thought at the time maybe it was a security feature in wicd, that it automatically disconnected after a certain time with no activity, rather than keeping a port open unnecessarily..

Comment: That doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll clarify. It doesn't make sense for wicd to disconnect from a wifi access point because a specific IP connection is open "too long". IP protocol is handled by the kernel and the traffic you push through wicd is of no concern to wicd. Wicd isn't even responsible for actually connecting to the wifi network, it asks the kernel to do that. And as a security feature it doesn't make sense either, wicd is not antivirus/firewall software and doesn't even handle the WPA encryption directly, that's done by kernel/drivers. It just allows you to configure some parts of the kernel.

Comment: Thank you for responding so explicitly to the question. I have no formal or professional knowledge of IT at all, but I have learnt to write bash code, so if I fail to find an answer to a problem online I tend to try writing a workaround.  Finding no answer for why wicd often disconnected my response was a bit of code that would keep at least minimal traffic moving through that connection.  And it seemed to do the trick, though it soon became irrelevant to me as I changed to Arch when I found Slackware would not install on my new computer, and began using netctl instead of wicd.